# new changes SharePoint 2013 to 2016

Tags: 2013, 2016

Differences and between SharePoint 2013 and 2016 and new changes in 2016
differences about functional level?

Architecture changes> Logical & physical

Migration changes SharePoint 2013 to 2016 databases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article shows Simply, [What’s new and deprecated features in SharePoint Server 2016](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/16/whats-new-in-sharepoint-and-project-server-2016-in-simple-words/) ?

it lists 34 new functional and features points, 10 deprecated features.

Check also,

- [Compare SharePoint 2016 Content Database limits with SharePoint 2013 / 2010 / 2007](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/06/22/comparing-a-content-database-limits-in-sharepoint-2016-with-sharepoint-201320102007)
- [Comparing a Web Application limits in SharePoint 2016 with SharePoint 2013 / 2010 / 2007](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/06/05/comparing-a-web-application-limits-in-sharepoint-2016-with-sharepoint-201320102007)
- [Compare SharePoint 2016 Site Collection limits with SharePoint 2013 / 2010 / 2007.](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/06/15/comparing-a-site-collection-limits-in-sharepoint-2016-with-sharepoint-201320102007)
- [Comparing List and Library limits in SharePoint 2016 with SharePoint 2013 / 2010 / 2007](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/07/05/compare-sharepoint-2016-list-library-limits-with-sharepoint-2013-2010/)